# Approaching a year's end?

Tags: usage

Work starts to pile up when **approaching a year's end**.
Is this correct usage?

When something always happens towards the end of the year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your usage is correct.

I would remove the *a*:

> Work starts to pile up when approaching **year's end**.

*A year's end* is very rare compared to *year's end*:

[image: NGram]

*Year's end* also has a [dictionary entry](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/year-s-end) and is commonly used.

Comment: Excellent answer. You've got an 8 instead of an * around one of the year's end entries. I would've edited it, but it's too small.

Comment: Where are you getting the data from?

Comment: @axk A Google NGram